# Editing large files on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, editor

Does anyone have any recommendations for a programmer's editor that can cope with large files on Mac OS X? By large I mean hundreds of megabytes. TextMate doesn't cut it.

Comment: Do you need interactive editing? Since a file that large will sort of exceed what a person's brain can handle, perhaps you could just pull chunks out of it and deal with those? Or use sed/perl/python/whatever to apply appropriate changes to a stream, and then feed the file in?

Comment: That's a very good point. It's actually an XML file and I just want to get an idea of its structure.

Comment: Vim also does folding in many languages, not sure if it supports XML though. Something to look into :-)

Comment: I used the XCode and it really open a 250mb easily :D

Comment: >5gb log file on a Haswell Core i7 iMac with 16GB and an SSD running Mavericks:

**TextMate:** opens an empty, one-line file with the right name and then sits there doing nothing.  I waited close to an hour before bailing on it.
**TextWrangler & BBEdit:** error immediately.
**Sublime Text 2:** progress bar for 9 minutes, then spinning wheel for two more, then perfect
**Console:** only 16MB chunks at a time. Can't view, scroll, or search the entire file at once.

Comment: **Crisp:** makes me register before I can download the trial.  Booooo.  Did not evaluate.
**XCode:** spinning wheel for five minutes; scrolling is fine, but editing and searching are terrible.
**MacVim:** opens a blank, white window.  no spinning wheel. 30 seconds later, file is open. Searching, editing, and scrolling are all excellent.

**Verdict:** Depending on your priorities, I give the win to Sublime Text 2 or MacVim.

Comment: Thanks [Crisp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535401/jakerobb) for taking the time of testing with those software clients

Comment: This question on Ask Different (where it isn't closed): https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/whats-the-best-text-editor-for-use-with-large-files

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Have you tried [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)? It's the only editor I use :-)

**Edit:** It seems to depend upon a couple of factors. I used Vim with large CSV (i.e. text-based) files and that worked great. YMMV :-)

Comment: If Vim can truly handle a file hundreds of megabytes in size, I tip my hat to it.  I know emacs chokes on enormously large files.

Comment: I use it on very large log files quite often. It only loads what it needs to. Now, doing some fun data manipulation on every line may take a while ;-)

Comment: Yes it can and search and replace is amazingly fast.

Comment: Vim worked like a charm for me so thanks for the suggestion. BBEdit was choking on only a 78 MB file and VIM opened it in seconds :)

Comment: FWIW I just opened a 4GB SQL dump file in vim on my MacBook Pro.  It took a minute to open, but it works...

Comment: I like vim, but not for this task. I want my xml editor to be able to collapse and expand xml nodes. That is a big plus. Upvotes here are very confusing to everybody.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Vim actually has support for code folding. Checkout this SO question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789605/how-do-i-enable-automatic-folds-in-vim

Comment: Just a comment- Huge VIM fan but tried to open a 3 GB file on both my Mac (MacVim) and on ubuntu using standard VIM and it is taking a very long time!

Comment: @SilentSteel - I honestly have seen the problem on newer versions of Vim; the old versions seemed to handle large files much better. I'm not sure if something changed or if we're just opening larger files these days...

Comment: Yeah--trying to open a 458MiB JSON file on vim on 10.12.x ... 30 minutes later, still isn't open.

Comment: Is this still the best tool for such a task, in 2017?

Comment: @Anupam Why not? Vim is a great tool and it handles large files well.

Comment: I just tried VIM to open a 30GB file and it did not work. 
It just sat there.

Answer (score 31):

If, as you say, only really need to get an idea of the structure try opening the document in Console.  Believe it or not, I'm able to view files as large as 15GB (MAC OSX 10.7.2)

Comment: Just tried this out and it's perfect for viewing large files on the Mac. It looks like it's made for viewing logs so have to learn how to use it a bit but it's very efficient at viewing large files. Thanks!

Comment: I just opened a 2.4GB text file in about 10 seconds using this.    PERFECT!!!    Can't recommend this enough.

Comment: Thank you! just opened a 16.95gb xml doc file.

Comment: Console does only open last 16 MB, that's why it seems fast! Please note the `Size: 8,7 GB (Showing last 16,8 MB)` in the status bar.

Comment: Correct, Tomas. Also hello, small world .)

Comment: What console app?

Answer (score 27):

[HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is designed to read files of any size, but you'll need to work using fixed-column character wrapping and no newline detection.

Comment: HexFiend is easily one of the fastest to *read* such a file as far as I've seen (5gb sql dump file opened in 3 seconds), but it's not really meant for *editing*.  Or, the menus don't seem to imply it.  Unless you know otherwise?

Comment: This worked for me - Even after Vim failed.

Comment: HexFiend opened up a 6gb json file in 1-2 seconds, without breaking a sweat

Comment: cannot handle UTF-8... https://github.com/ridiculousfish/HexFiend/issues/247

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to have an idea of structure, how about browsing with **more** or **less**?

Comment: Very good advice: if you only need to read the content, less is even more efficient than vi.

Answer (score 11):

Definitely vim is the answer. Check out the [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/), the mac version.

Comment: Could you explain how vim works? For me it only shows the top or the bottom of the file and does not respond to moving arrows up and down nor to clicking...

Answer (score 7):

[BBEdit](http://bbedit.com/), that old standby, is famous for handling really large files with aplomb (or, at least, it was back in the pre-TextMate era). There's a free version, [TextWranger](http://bbedit.com/products/textwrangler/); I assume it's based on the same core and should still work.

Comment: I tried TextWrangler and it choked on the file unfortunately.

Comment: The latest BBEdit crashed on my 4GB file.  I do typically use it for hundred-meg files, but it can't handle GB size files apparently.

Comment: TextWrangler and BBEdit can edit any file up to 384MB. This limit is because they store the entire file in RAM, and it's unicode encrypted so it's not very efficient. I recently used `split -b 300m foo.xml` on a huge XML file, and TextWrangler took several seconds to open it, but then was fully functional - even syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert encoded, you meant to say encoded

Answer (score 4):

I have used **`gvim`** for files larger than 1 GB of [NASTRAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASTRAN) output.
**`gvim`** handles large files very well.
In fact that was the main reason I switched from **`Emacs`** to vim.

**`Emacs`** is a great editor but it can handle files only as large as 128 MB, at least the 32-bit version. If you decide to use **`Emacs`** I recommend to configure it to turn syntax highlighting off for large files.

Another way to deal with large files those days was heavy usage of **`head`**, **`tail`** and **`split`**.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has already been recommended. If you're using vim you might want to also use the [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin (by the inimitable Charles "Dr Chip" Campbell), which automatically disables various features of vim in the interests of speed for files over 100Mb (at the default setting).

Answer (score 3):

The native emacs on OS X seems to be the 64-bit version now.  It works like a charm on my 250MB text file.

Answer (score 1):

emacs, naturally, at least a 64 bit build  (you can do that on OS X now, right?)

But also, these are surely generated files.  Do you really need to interact with them all at once?

Comment: As far as I know, Emacs can only handle up to 128 MB.
Not sure about 64 versions.

Comment: yes to 128mb limit on 32.  I should double check this about 64 bit builds on OS X, as it is funny about 64 bit in some ways

Answer (score 1):

Since you noted in a comment that it's actually an XML file and you just want to get an idea of its structure, you may want to check out [Oxygen's](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) LargeFileViewer, a helper app which is bundled with Oxygen XML Editor. (It might also come with Author, I don't know.)

Answer (score -2):

[Crisp](http://www.crisp.com/News/CRiSP-Available-For-Mac-Platform.html) claims the ability to edit files of "8GB or more", but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -3):

Edit: Do not use Sublime Text 2!
Although it worked for me, apparently for many other users Sublime Text 2 can't handle large text files. 
Below is my original answer:

---

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) for Mac 10.6.8 opened up a 200 MB file for me without any problem

Comment: Just tried it with 180MB SQL file. Opens file for minutes, tries to load whole file to memory. No good

Comment: If you are coding 180MB SQL files, I think you are possibly "doing it wrong". (Oh it's an export? well i forgive you then)

Comment: Sublime Text 3 basically hangs when doing find & replace on large files.

Comment: Very awesome text editor, but not its strong suit.

Comment: I keep getting negative feedback on my answer, and I believe all those who downvoted this answer, that my answer was not correct for their use case. Indeed perhaps the only use case my answer was correct is my use case :-). I'm contemplating what to do? should I remove this answer and get some points back to my reputation? I've decided to keep this answer - as a warning to future viewers of this question. DO  NOT USE SUBLIME TEXT 2! it appears to not be good for most users.

Comment: ST is great, but not for opening huge files. e.g.: > 1 GB (though if I recall right even 500 MB is getting annoying, on a 2014 MBP.)