# Don't fold me this way

Tags: javascript, vim, folding

**Fold 3** below fold in lines *below* the end of the function. How can I make this fold in the expected way (*to preserve the lines below the end of function*):

Code :

```
(function() {
        var w = window; // <-- FOLD 1 pressed HERE
        function pqdoitall () {
                // insertScript
                // fr2window 
                // pqinsert2windowDoc
                // pqinsert2window
                // runit
                //runit(); // <-- FOLD 2 pressed HERE
        } // pqdoitall
        w.addEventListener("load",pqtdoitall);
        pqtdoitall(); // <-- FOLD 3 pressed HERE
})();
```

Fold 1 Result:

```
(function() {----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Fold 2 Result:

```
(function() {
        var w = window;
  function pqdoitall () {----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Fold 3 Result:

```
(function() {
        var w = window;
  function pqdoitall () {----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is quite annoying since I would like to see the two lines below the function terminating brace when I fold it.

Foldmethod lines in ~/.vimrc (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789615/907415)) :

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldlevelstart=1

let javaScript_fold=1         " JavaScript
let perl_fold=1               " Perl
let php_folding=1             " PHP
let r_syntax_folding=1        " R
let ruby_fold=1               " Ruby
let sh_fold_enabled=1         " sh
let vimsyn_folding='af'       " Vim script
let xml_syntax_folding=1      " XML
```

Comment: I use `set foldmethod=indent`. It's a lot "dumber" than `syntax` but much more coherent across languages.

Comment: Sometimes dumb is works.

Comment: @romainl I much prefer that. It looks really good, please make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. While this is not a *real* answer to your question, I've found the `syntax` folding method a lot more disappointing than the "dumber" `indent` method which produces more coherent results across languages.

`set foldmethod=indent` is all I use.

Comment: Well, it suggests the question is itself kind of ill-posed, since the method I'm asking for an answer for, is actually inferior to the one your propose. I'd say that's *as real as it gets.* :)